# Missing original values when converting csv file to dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

I have a csv file which looks like this-

[image]

I've read it and stored it in a dataframe as follows:

```
query_df=spark.read.csv('./rules/rules.csv',header=True)
query_df.show(truncate=False)
```

However when I view this dataframe using the .show() method above, a part of the last value under the 'Query' column is getting omitted:

[image]

Note that the rounding to 2 decimal places and 'form {table}' of the original string is omitted. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Probably because of the comma. Since you are reading CSV spark might be treating the things after comma as separate column. try having quotes like `"select .... *100,2"`. It normally shows an error as well but not sure why you don't have any errors

Comment: force add quotes while writing the csv file. or write the csv file with a different delimiter.